# can I skip some request params in servlet request?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I have following url to call my application: 
    http://machine.domain.com:8383/eqube70/BuildNPlay 
This works great and it calles index.jsp as per my expectations.

But if my request url is changed as: 
    http://machine.domain.com:8383/eqube70/BuildNPlay/?--%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('you got  hacked')%3C/script%3E 
Then I get the alert and I am not able to get my application working.

This is because through request URI some request params are passed.
In order to remove this I wrote requiest wrapper to scan param values.
If param value contain character such as <, > then I am replacing them with &lt, &gt respectively.

Now this works great if my request param values. But if newly passed request param names contain any of these chars then I am getting alert.

I want some way to scan request param names and remove/modify or skip the param names with malicious chars.

Is there anything I can do to achieve this?

Following is my code which I wrote so far.

```
public class eQIndexServlet implements Filter 
{
static class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper 
{
    char[] ESCAPECHARS = { '&', '<', '>'};

    public RequestWrapper(ServletRequest request) 
    {
        super((HttpServletRequest)request);
    }

    public String getParameter(String paramName) 
    {
        //if(paramName.contains(ESCAPECHARS))
        String value = super.getParameter(paramName);


        value = eQUtil.escapeHtmlCharArray(value, ESCAPECHARS);

        return value;
    }

    public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) 
    {
        String values[] = super.getParameterValues(paramName);

        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = eQUtil.escapeHtmlCharArray(values[i], ESCAPECHARS);
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use servlet filters to validate the request..

Comment: Hi SivaS, I have already written servlet filer to validate param values. But I dont ubnderstand how can I valuidate param names and again set the param back on request. Can u please provide me sampe code to validate param names and pushing the modified param name on requst?

Comment: You cannot set/remove parameters from the request. You have to wrap in a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` the request and do the filtering in there. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest for inspiration. See http://www.hdiv.org for an implementation which will also guard you against other attacks.

Comment: Hi have already wrapped HttpServletRequestWrapper and added logic for filtering. But if I am not wrong that can only be applied for filtering request param values and not for keys. I would appreciate if you can give me the sample code to change parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

After adding following code in getparameter method it worked

if(paramName.contains(">") || paramName.contains("<"))
   return null;

it seems that if value is null then chain.doFilter ignores the paramter.